# What is the best way for deploying Oracle EBS developments?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-ebs

I am planning to deploy my developments from one instance to another, how should i proceed, what is the best practice about this process, I want to deploy DB objects(Tables, packages, views etc.) and application objects (Concurrent programs, messages, lookups etc.), Thanks for help.

Comment: Broad question, narrow answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice to deploy database objects is

1. Have creation/modification script text files stored in a version control system.
2. Run the scripts from version control with `sqlplus`.

Note that you don't create/modify database objects in database with a GUI-tool but write the SQL in text files with a text editor.

The best practice to deploy eBS objects is

1. Save the objects from an eBS instance to text files with [Generic Loader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12893/T174296T206863.htm) `fndload`.
2. Save the text files into a version control system.
3. Load the text files to another eBS instance(s) with `fndload`.

Here the objects are created in one eBS instance and then saved in to version control system and copied to other instances.

`fndload` example for concurrent programs:

```
ebs-1$ FNDLOAD apps/<PASSWD> O Y DOWNLOAD $FND_TOP/patch/115/import/afcpprog.lct <CONCURRENT_NAME>_program.ldt PROGRAM APPLICATION_SHORT_NAME=<APP_NAME> CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_NAME=<CONCURRENT_NAME>
ebs-2$ FNDLOAD apps/<PASSWD> O Y UPLOAD $FND_TOP/patch/115/import/afcpprog.lct <CONCURRENT_NAME>_program.ldt -
```